# Using Draft js mention plugin with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I have been trying to get draft js mention plugin to work with react hooks but can't seem to figure what's wrong with the code. Appreciate any help on this.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { EditorState } from "draft-js";
import Editor from "draft-js-plugins-editor";
import createMentionPlugin, { defaultSuggestionsFilter } from "draft-js-mention-plugin";
import mentions from "./mentions";

export default function MentionEditor() {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState(mentions);
  const editor = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    editor.current.focus();
  }, [])

  const mentionPlugin = createMentionPlugin();
  const { MentionSuggestions } = mentionPlugin;
  const plugins = [mentionPlugin];

  const onSearchChange = ({ value }) => {
    setSuggestions(defaultSuggestionsFilter(value, mentions))
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid gray" }}>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onChange={editorState => setEditorState(editorState)}
        plugins={plugins}
        ref={editor}
      />
      <MentionSuggestions
        onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
        suggestions={suggestions}
      />
    </div> 
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as well! were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move the draft-js plugin configuration outside the component arrow function. This is a pretty basic Draft-JS implementation using a functional component and hooks:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js'
import Editor from 'draft-js-plugins-editor'
import createMentionPlugin, { defaultSuggestionsFilter } from 'draft-js-mention-plugin'
import 'draft-js/dist/Draft.css'
import 'draft-js-mention-plugin/lib/plugin.css'
import mentions from "./mentions"

// Draft-JS-Mentions plugin configuration
const mentionPlugin = createMentionPlugin()
const { MentionSuggestions } = mentionPlugin
const plugins = [mentionPlugin]

const MyEditor= () => {
    const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState(mentions)

    // Draft-JS editor configuration
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
        () => EditorState.createEmpty(),
    )
    const editor = useRef(null)

    // Check editor text for mentions
    const onSearchChange = ({ value }) => {
        setSuggestions(defaultSuggestionsFilter(value, mentions))
    }

    const onAddMention = () => {

    }

    // Focus on editor window
    const focusEditor = () => {
        editor.current.focus()
    }

    return (
            <div onClick={() => focusEditor()}>
                <Editor
                    ref={editor}
                    editorState={editorState}
                    plugins={plugins}
                    onChange={editorState => setEditorState(editorState)}
                    placeholder={'Type here...'}
                />
                <MentionSuggestions
                    onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
                    suggestions={suggestions}
                    onAddMention={onAddMention}
                />
            </div>
    )
}

export default MyEditor
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move these lines outside component and it will work:

```
  const mentionPlugin = createMentionPlugin();
  const { MentionSuggestions } = mentionPlugin;
  const plugins = [mentionPlugin];

export default function MentionEditor() {
        const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
.. ... ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   **PAY ATTENTION**  !!!!!!!!!!!!

The **onSearchChange** method will be triggered once the '@' character is typed, so in this case it will return just 5 items that fit the empty string...

To prevent this to be happened, just check that the value we want to search is **not** **empty**:

```
const onSearchChange = ({ value }) => {
    if (value) {
      setSuggestions(defaultSuggestionsFilter(value, mentions));
    }
  };
```